# Surprise holiday booked for me - what do I do?

Tags: time-off, holidays

A family member booked a surprise holiday for me to the other side of the world from the 28th of December to the 5th or 6th of January.

I started working in my current workplace at the end of September.
My expected date of termination is the 31st of December but it is quite possible I will be kept on for another month or so after that and will possibly be asked back during summer time.

Should I just quit and leave the job on the 28th? Or should I request time off even though I'm probably not eligible for it and possibly get turned down - and then quit? Or cancel the holiday :(

Comment: You have the options. What do you want? How expensive is the trip? Did family member take out travel insurance? What would happen if you declined your family member gift? Are you going by yourself or with family and friends?
It will likely be very awkward requesting time off from your job.

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't want to turn down a free vacation.  It's only a week long. Why not ask your manager if you can take off for that time period and then come back?  In many places, not much work gets done between Christmas and New Years anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Go to your management.  Explain the situation, including the fact that it was done without your knowledge.  Tell them that you'd really rather not cancel the holiday trip.  Ask them, NICELY, if they can accommodate the holiday time.

Assuming that this is in fact a place you want to be working and a job you want to be doing (as opposed to, say, a telemarketer pushing dodgy penny stock deals), the odds are pretty good that they'll say something like "We can live with that.  Go have fun!"

If you ask, the worst that can happen is they say no, and you have the same problem you have now.  If they say yes, you're home free.

Comment: Hey, some people love pushing dodgy penny stocks. Didn't you see Wolf of Wall Street?